# How to initialize bootstrap controls added dynamically to the page?

Tags: bootstrap-accordion

If an accordion, for example, exists on the page when the page is loaded, it works.  However, if I add the identical accordion markup to the page dynamically after it has loaded, it does not work.

Is there a global method of initializing bootstrap controls that I can call after the page has loaded? All I can find is code snippets attempting to re-implement click handler logic, which seems unreasonable, if there is a simpler/global initialization method that can be called. Other suggestions like calling the 'collapse' method on elements that have the '.collapse' class will make something collapsible, but the accordion still does not work correctly. I can collapse individual panels, but when one expands, the others don't automatically close. There has got to be a more obvious and straightforward way to handle this that doesn't involve reinventing the wheel, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't find any official documentation on this topic. But, when I looked at the implementation of the JS side of Bootstrap, I have found that it simply listens to the page load events and processes only those elements that are already on the page. So, I don't think this is possible to do in the current version of Bootstrap without going deep into their code and dealing with internals.

Comment: It really is unbelievable that there is no public idempotent initialization method for new controls.  I looked into the source code the Collapse plugin, and it seems to merge the 'options' as an object if it's not a string. In that case, I can call 'collapse({parent:$parentElementOrId})', and it will register the children correctly to collapse.  For example, instead of just calling $panelGroup.find('.collapse').collapse(), I change that last method to be .collapse({parent:$panelGroup}) and it works.